# smoothScollToPosition doesn't go from right to left

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an horizontal recyclerview. In my view holder, when I click a button, I need to center that button. I use this method:

```
myRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
```

The problem is that is only go from left to right. For example, If I Click on a button to the left of the actual selected button, it doesn't move. But if I click on a button to the right of the selected button, then It moves correctly the recycler and it center the selected button...What should I do/check?

Comment: Please provide the related code.

Comment: I found that i need to set a negative position to slide from right to left